# date formatting returns 12 hour format even when locale idenifier en_GB set

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

```
+(NSDate *)DateServerFormatFromString:(NSString *)date
{
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate* returnDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
return returnDate;
```

}

The function returns date in format "2013-05-09 08:06:04 AM +0000". But i want it in 24 hour format. The date being passed to this function is in the exact same format as given in setDateFormat method.
The device's region format is set to "United Kingdom" and time format is set to "12 hour format". This should not be changed. When time format is set to 24 hour format in the device, the function works perfectly. What is wrong with the code. I am using iPad 1 with OS 5.1.1.   Setting locale identifer or even timezone didnt make a difference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you getting `"2013-05-09 08:06:04 AM +0000"` from?

Comment: by printing the description of returnDate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not necessarily an answer, just an explanation, found in the Apple docs ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)):

> Although in principle a format string specifies a fixed format, by
>   default NSDateFormatter still takes the user’s preferences (including
>   the locale setting) into account. You must consider the following
>   points when using format strings:
>
> - NSDateFormatter treats the numbers in a string you parse as if they
>     were in the user’s chosen calendar. For example, if the user selects
>     the Buddhist calendar, parsing the year 2010 yields an NSDate object
>     in 1467 in the Gregorian calendar. (For more about different
>     calendrical systems and how to use them, see Date and Time Programming
>     Guide.)
> - **In iOS, the user can override the default AM/PM versus 24-hour
>     time setting. This may cause NSDateFormatter to rewrite the format
>     string you set.**

Comment: the calender is set as gregorian in all devices i checked. The second point seems to be the problem. Any idea on how to override it and force 24 hour format?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is how you're getting the string.  You say you got it

> by printing the description of returnDate

However, according to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188--description), the `-description` method says this:

> The representation is useful for debugging only.
>
> There are a number of options to aquire a formated string for a date including: date formatters (see NSDateFormatter and Data Formatting Guide), and the NSDate methods descriptionWithLocale:, dateWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:, and descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:

What this means is that the value returned by `-description` does *not* respect any 12- or 24-hour time settings.  It's just a debug version.

If you want to express a date as a human-readable string, you *must* use an `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

Again and again:

Did you `NSLog()` the date? Logging a date is always been done in a normalized standard format. If you want to log a date formatted, log the result of a formatter, not the date directly.

Comment: i tried logging the result of formatter. ITs still returning 12 hour format.

Comment: The string result of the formatter would no do that, if it is set-up properly.

Answer (score 0):

You want 24h format for what? Format is used to convert `NSDate` to `NSString` with correct string format. Just make reverse converting when you need it

Answer (score -2):

12 hour format

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
```

24 hour format

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: as you can see, i am using 24 hour format but it returns 12 hour format.